# Are there any rewards for collecting all ampersands in Type Rider?

Tags: type-rider

I just finished playing the artistic platform Type Rider, but the platforming part was too frustrating to me. This means I didn't go back to collect everything that there was to collect, such as the ampersands.

Do they unlock anything, aside from a Steam achievement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the achievements are rewarded. The only "extra" thing to find/unlock is the last level, "Comic Sans", but that can be found regardless of how many collectibles you have picked up along the way.

The "Comic Sans" level can be found after the credits, when the moon is big. Just head back in the water.